# I am trying to create multiple tab in my nw application and in the tab i would like to implement attach and detach tab window like browser

Tags: node.js, tabs, node-webkit

I am trying to create multiple tab in my nw application and in the tab i would like to implement attach and detach tab window like browser tab drag outside of window browser open new window. Still I am researching on the same. If someone know about the same. Please help me

Comment: Please can you clarify your question? It will better allow users to help with your query.

Comment: Actually, I just want to develop tabs in my application and tabs behavior look like browser tabs. If you check the browser tab and drag tab outside of window then tab open a speprate window. and if you drag in the previous window then it will merge in first window. Same thing i just want to implement in my node-webkit application. I have created few buttons and each button I have added event for open tab thats working but if I tried to drag tab outside of window then it's not work open new instance. I have used the tab script [https://github.com/adamschwartz/chrome-tabs]

Comment: http://adamschwartz.co/chrome-tabs/

how we can drag tab outside and open new window